# Communication between services in a Shared VPC for GKE

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I set up this configuration for my projects:

https://cloud.google.com/vpc/images/shared-vpc/shared-vpc-example-two-tier.svg

Everything is running under Google Kubernetes Engine.

- NodeJS service in Tier 1 Service project with subnet: 10.0.4.0/22

must connect to a

- NodeJS API in Tier 2 service project with subnet:
  172.16.4.0/22 which is deploy behind an Internal LB:

.

```
kubectl describe svc gateway-node-api  --namespace master

Name:                     gateway-node-api
Namespace:                master
Labels:                   app=node-api
                          chart=node-api-0.1.2
                          heritage=Tiller
                          release=gateway-node-api
Annotations:              cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type=Internal
Selector:                 app=node-api,release=gateway-node-api
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       172.16.23.21
LoadBalancer Ingress:     172.16.4.5
Port:                     http  3000/TCP
TargetPort:               http/TCP
NodePort:                 http  31386/TCP
Endpoints:                172.20.2.30:3000
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
```

Using 172.16.4.5:3000 in the Tier 1 NodeJS service doesn't connect to Tier 2 NodeJS API.

What could I have possibly missed?

Answer (score 1):

Found my problem, I didn't read enough the firewall rules documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls

After configuring my Shared VPC, I created a rule applying for all the network for all incoming request:

```
shared-network-allow-ssh-icmp    shared-network  INGRESS    1000      icmp,tcp:22,tcp:80
```

And realize that I also need to apply a rule that allow all instances of the network to be accessible on all tcp port when receiving a request from the subnetwork of Tier 1 service:

```
service1-allow-tcp               shared-network  INGRESS    1000      tcp:1-65535
```